# Importing a CATIA 3D Model file (*.model) into Blender

Tags: import, conversion

I'm hitting a brick wall trying to import a **.model* file into Blender.

The kind of model I tried to import is a file with the *.model* file extension. It's a kind of CAD model, *CATIA 3D* according to the [fileinfo.com](https://fileinfo.com/extension/model) site. Blender's import feature doesn't cover this model type. I don't have access to any CAD software myself. Otherwise, I'd save it as a *.stl* file and move on. Haven't been able to find a reliable way of converting a *.model* file either. I'm at a loss.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you want a satisfactory answer, you need to give us more details. What kind of model did you try to import? What have you tried? What went wrong? The normal way to import a file is to use the menu *File > Import > ...*

Comment: The kind of model I tried to import is a .model file. It's a kind of CAD model. Blender's import feature doesn't cover this model type. I don't have access to any CAD software myself. Otherwise I'd save it as an .stl file and move on. Haven't been able to find a reliable way of converting a .model file either. I'm at a loss.

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a standard format. What program created it?

Comment: @TheLabCat https://fileinfo.com/extension/model

Comment: yes, looks like Catia v4 (https://www.okino.com/conv/imp_catia5.htm) and (https://youtu.be/ra9bdt1uEFI). Have you tried this Okino PolyTrans demo?

Comment: I did. My antivirus kept flagging it during the installation. Spooked me a bit so I gave up and kept looking. Maybe I'll have to go back and try it?

Comment: uh. If you're worried you can install it in a VirtualBox or VM. It's officially recommended for Mac users (because it requires Windows). Windows requires a license to activate it. But you can use it for 30 days without activation.